# How to have forward search using Zathura PDF viewer and LaTeX-Box plugin?

Tags: search, plugin-latex-box

I just started using Zathura to view pdfs while editing tex files.

I am trying to have forward searching capability in Zathura.

Using the LaTeX-Box plugin in Vim, I have added the following in my vimrc:

```
let g:LatexBox_viewer= '/usr/bin/zathura --fork --synctex-editor-command "vim --servername VIM --remote +\%{line} \%{input}"'
```

This gives me backward searching capability when I open a tex file with:

```
vim --servername VIM filename.tex
```

and open the corresponding PDF file by typing `<LocalLeader>lv` (this automatically opens the corresponding PDF file in Zathura).

But I do not know how to have forward searching.

Comment: Forward search with zathura should work out of the box with [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex). If you like LaTeX-Box, then you might also like vimtex, as it was originally based off of LaTeX-Box.

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg funnily enough my googling led me to this: https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/118 Tried a bit to get LaTeX-Box to work building on suggestions there, but got bored.

Comment: @muru Yes, I also find this stuff to be quite a hazzle. I am relatively happy with how it works in my plugin right now (although there are still room for many improvements, I guess). If caffeinemachine wants to keep using LaTeX-Box, the issue you've linked to might provide some helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

First you must compile your doc with synctex option:
To do reverse search add the following:

```
# Adding reverse search between gvim and zathura
set synctex true
set synctex-editor-command "gvim --remote-silent +%{line} %{input}"
```

to your zathurarc file (Usually it can be find in your $HOME/.config/zathura folder). 
You can jump to line 150 column 2 by running:

```
zathura --synctex-forward 150:2:foo.tex foo.pdf
```

See also [How to do reverse and forward search using vim and zathura](https://magmath.com/vim-how-to-use-reverse-and-forward-search-with-vim-and-zathura.html).

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! The network in general discourages link-only answers (because of link-rot, for one). Please [edit] your answer to include more details and provide an actual solution.